# Copy text of single cell to clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, cell, gridcontrol

My CurrentCellValue is always null.

I want to mark a row but also if I choose to copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) a cell I want that value to be copied, now I get the whole row.

```xaml
<dxg:GridControl
    Name="GridControl"
    ColumnsSource="{Binding Columns}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
    ColumnGeneratorTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnTemplate}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="None"
    ColumnGeneratorStyle="{StaticResource CommonColumnStyle}"
    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedOrders}"
    SelectionMode="Row"
    CustomSummary="GridControl_OnCustomSum"
    SelectionChanged="GridControl_OnSelectionChanged"       
    CopyingToClipboard="GridControl_OnCopyingToClipboard">
```

```cs
private void GridControl_OnCopyingToClipboard(object sender, CopyingToClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
    Clipboard.SetText(GetRowData());
    e.Handled = true;
}

private string GetRowData()
{
    return GridControl.CurrentCellValue.ToString();
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

```xaml
 <dxg:TableView Name="GridTableView" NavigationStyle="Cell" />
```

Now I have a value in CurrentCellValue

Answer (score 0):

1. If there's only one cell that you may wish to copy text from:

You can add "SelectedItem" Binding to your GridControl, and in "GridControl_OnCopyingToClipboard" try to find inside the selectedItem the relevant text that you want to copy.

2. If there're several cells in a row that you may wish to copy from them, and it really matters which one you clicked on inside same row, then you might want to reconsider this line:
   SelectionMode="Row"... And change "Row" to "Cell", then again add "SelectedItem" Binding as I mentioned above, and get the text from it

Comment: I only want to copy one cell. Tried adding a selectedItem but I still can't see what is selected, I set the every element in the row.